# What is the difference between a string and a "binary" string in PHP?

Tags: php

In PHP, you can (since PHP 5.2.1) use "binary strings":

```
$binary = (binary) $string;
$binary = b"binary string";
```

**What is the difference with a "normal" string?**

The only meaningful insight I could find was [this comment](http://php.net/manual/fr/language.types.string.php#93576):

> However, it will only have effect as of PHP 6.0.0, as noted on http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-binary.php .

The link is dead. It would actually make sense that binary strings were added in PHP while PHP 6.0 was being developed, since 6.0 was supposed to bring Unicode support. So it was sort of a premature feature.

However is there an official source that could confirm that? I.e. confirm that there is absolutely no difference between classic strings and binary strings?

Comment: I believe i have found it in the source:  http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/Zend/zend_language_scanner.l#1227 which looks like its identical `1227<ST_IN_SCRIPTING>"("{TABS_AND_SPACES}("string"|"binary"){TABS_AND_SPACES}")" {
1228    return T_STRING_CAST;
1229}`

Comment: @Dagon Honestly this bit of code doesn't really speak to me ;)

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any official source to back this up, but I believe the reason is simple:

The present PHP treats strings as byte arrays, i.e. as raw binary blobs. PHP 6 was slated to be this great new release with its biggest improvement being native Unicode handling. At that point, a string literal would actually be understood as a string of characters instead as a string of bytes. Many string handling functions would break because of this and a lot of code would need to be retrofitted to continue to work in PHP 6.

As a migration path, strings could be declared as binary strings to keep the current behaviour. This was added early on to give developers ample time to prepare their code for PHP 6 compatibility. At the moment `b` doesn't do anything, the changed behaviour would only show up in PHP 6.

Well, PHP 6 never happened and is [dead for now](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#PHP_6_and_Unicode). So, `b` continues to do nothing for the time being and for now it's questionable if it will ever have any specific use in the future.

Comment: Thanks. Yes this is what I hinted in my question. I'm trying to find a source to make sure that's actually the case ;)